# How to stop extra messages from junit while running it using ant?

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am running junits using ant in a foreach loop .
[Using This Solution](http://solutionsdaily.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/making-junit-tests-run-parallely.html)

I am getting the output in following format in my console

```
[junit] Running com.test.MyUnitTest
[foreach] junit.framework.TestListener: startTest(testMyMethod)
[foreach] junit.framework.TestListener: endTest(testMyMethod)
[junit] Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.109 sec
```

How to stop TestListener messages, so that output is in the format

```
[junit] Running com.test.MyUnitTest
[junit] Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.109 sec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uses  internally, the result is that for each
iteration you get an invocation of , thus the target gets
started once per iteration and you get the target's label once per
iteration using DefaultLogger.

ANT-CONTRIB cannot control what is output from that. The output is
part of the core definition of the "Target" class.